# What is the best way get subdocument's property with ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections: Docs and Types.
In Docs i have document:

```js
{
    '_id': ObjectId('0000'),
    'name': 'someName',
    'type': ObjectId('1111') // id i have
}
```

In Types:

```js
{
    '_id': ObjectId('2222'),
    'for': 'Docs',
    'types': [
        {
            '_id': ObjectId('1111'), // type i need
            'name': 'someType' // want to get this name
        }
         // , and so on
    ]
}
```

After `Docs.findOne({_id: '0000'})` i have `type = ObjectId('1111')` (id of 'someType'). What is the best way to get someType's name value?

Comment: That's sort of an awkward schema.  Can you make `Types` a collection of {_id, name} type docs instead of embedding the type definitions inside the `types` property?

Comment: Conception provides many Type-groups (Types collection contains type-groups) for different collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator) positional operator in your field selection parameter to `findOne` to pull out just the matching element:

```
Types.findOne({'types._id': someTypeId}, {'types.$': 1}, function (err, type) {
    if (type) {
        console.log('Type name is: ' + type.types[0].name);
    }
});
```

Comment: `console.log(type);` returns `{_id: ..., types: [undefined, undefined, ...]}`

Comment: @0xBADC0FFEE What version of MongoDB are you using?  This may only work in v2.2.